# Solving large system of coupled differential equations

Tags: matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods

I have a system of coupled ordinary differential equations
`dx/dt = (A + C_d(t) * B) * x`,
where A and B are constant matrices and C_d is a diagonal coefficient matrix which smoothly varies depending on the current value of the integration variable.

The square matrices A and B are built up from smaller 60*60 upper triangular or zero matrices. The dimension of the full system is around 2500*2500. A and B are sparse with ~10% non-zero elements. The diagonal elements are negative or zero. The main (physical) constraint is that elements of x(t) are not allowed to become negative during integration.

Currently, I employ a ‘naïve’ step solver
`x_(i+1) = A * x_i * dt_i  + B * (C_d(t_i) * x_i) * dt_i + x_i`
or in the CPU/GPU versions

```
def solve_CPU(nsteps, dt, c_d, x):
    for step in xrange(nsteps): 
        x += (A.dot(x) + B.dot(x * c_d[step])) * dt[step]

def solve_GPU(m, n, nsteps, dt, c_d, cu_curr_x, cu_delta_x, cu_A, cu_B):
    for step in xrange(nsteps): 
        cubl.gemv(trans='T', m=m, n=n, alpha=1.0, A=cu_A,
                  x=cu_curr_x, beta=0.0, y=cu_delta_x)
        cubl.gemv(trans='T', m=m, n=n, alpha=c_d[step], A=cu_B,
                  x=cu_curr_x, beta=1.0, y=cu_delta_x)
        cubl.axpy(alpha=dt[step], x=cu_delta_x, y=cu_curr_x)
```

and make use of a feature, that the step sizes `dt_i`this can be computed *a priory* in a way that the elements of x are always >=0 during integration. Depending on the amount of approximations and the settings the number of integration steps varies between 25k and 10M.

I  have tried several methods to optimize performance on general purpose hardware:

- (unknown) When using ODEPACK’s VODE solver, I do not know how to express the x>=0 constraint
- (slowest) Dense BLAS 2 dot-product using Intel MKL
- (medium) Dense BLAS using single precision cuBLAS on NVIDIA GPU
- (fastest) SCIPY sparse module using CSR/CSC formats

The code is written in Python and has access to the above listed libraries via Anaconda, Numba, Accelerate, Numpy etc. SCIPY's sparse BLAS routines are not properly linked to MKL in Anaconda and Python wrappers around cuSPARSE are to my knowledge not available, yet. I would know how to squeeze out a little bit more performance by directly interfacing to cuSPARSE/C-MKL sparse dot product, but that’s it. This exercise has to be solved dozens of times, again and again if models change, so performance is always an issue. I’m not an expert in this matter, so I don’t know much about preconditioners, factorization theorems etc. what brings me to my question:

Is there a more elegant or better way to solve such a linear-algebra task?

Comment: Is the step size dt_i much smaller than the rate of variation of the function C_d(t_i)? If yes, a more sophisticated integrator scheme that incorporates the constraint and can use longer time steps can help. Second question: why don't you just clip any negative values to zero after the calculation? If negative values occur due to numerical imprecision, and you work around that via selecting time steps beforehand, the results will not tell you how close the solution came to zero (because numerical imprecision is bigger). [cf](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/support/notes.html#disc)

Comment: Many thanks to pointing me to the properties if the function C_d(t_i). I haven't tried to look for features in it, yet. It is a line in loglog, therefore not slowly varying. Your second question: I tried capping the x-vector in the solver function of VODE. It turned out to be slower. I guess because VODE's error estimation routines get confused? Or: if you mean 'after the calculation' = 'when it's done', the problem is that the equations are **coupled** and the eigenmodes have Re<0. Than negative x mess up other states during integration, or in other words magic energy is added to the system.

Comment: Your equations are linear, so I don't immediately see a mathematical reason why avoiding negative values of `x` would matter --- that the equations are coupled etc. should be irrelevant for the accuracy of the solution. You could try capping the values when the integrator is done (so that you don't mess up the smoothness of the integrand), and the compare the accuracy to your other method. Also, if you are interested in conserving energy or some other physical quantity, it may be useful to look into symplectic or variational integrators, which have exact conservation properties.

Comment: I tried ignoring negative values and the solution diverges. The system is a cascade equation for particle creation and decay. Thus, negative values mean negative particle populations. So if more particles decay that were available, they start to create their mothers, what is kind of strange :) One can look at the system as a more complex predator-prey model. The system is linearized, so choosing too large dt results in invalidation of linearized range. The autonomous solutions of the decoupled system would be exponentials, which never become zero. I'll look at your suggested integrator types.

Comment: If you can add citations to papers where the problem is formulated, that could be helpful.

Comment: Good general literature on (Air Shower) Cascade Equation is T. K. Gaisser, Cosmic Rays and Particle Physics (Cambridge Univ Pr, 1990). The matrix method above is sketched in chapter 4 of our [conference proceedings](http://143.107.180.38/indico/contributionDisplay.py?contribId=1144&sessionId=3&confId=0), the paper is the zip file in the bottom left. References therein point to other numerical solutions. There was some uptick in complexity and understanding due to ongoing research, though.

Comment: Thanks, interesting physics. There's some [literature on positivity constraints](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300304009683), but implementing those yourself may be not worth the trouble. However, the article mentions that DASSL has positivity constraints, and there is a [PyDAS](https://github.com/jwallen/PyDAS) wrapper for that. The main hope in using a smarter solver would be in getting a larger time step; but it depends on your C(t). You may also want to ask this question on scicomp.stackexchange.com, as that forum might be more relevant for this numerics question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your definitely helpful comments and the reference to the paper. I could extract very valuable information from it. First, it seems that I haven't overlooked something obvious. And second, the logarithmic nature of the computing task and of the function C(t) is mainly responsible for the behavior of the solver. I have the impression that things might change if the problem could be reformulated  somehow as dx/d(ln t). I will investigate further and ask on scicomp, which I didn't know before your reference.